# SetValue is not behaving as expected

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase in an iOS app written using Swift.

```
    static func createUserRecord(uid: String, user: User){
       let userDictionary = user.getJSON()
       self.usersRef.child(uid).setValue(userDictionary)
    }
```

This code was working just fine before I release my app and after releasing the app I could not get user records added anymore, All other functionalities of the app are working fine, including saving and retrieving some data. Can anyone spot the error in this code?

Does `setValue` works even if the path was not there ? e.g. if the path `a/b/` is there, and I called `a/b/c.child('d').setValue("abcd")`. Will this work?

Comment: Are your Firebase security rules set up to allow this data to be saved?

Comment: Calling `setValue()` will create the path if it doesn't exist yet. It seems more likely that your `user.getJSON` contains something that is invalid according to the database (or your security rules). You'll want to attach a completion block to detect this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference.html#a1107cae145ab12e1ef58ab9f8713b84d

Comment: @chickenparm Yes they are both true for read and write, I got another problem with uploading pics to storage,(it was working just fine an hour ago) could this be a bandwidth issue? should I consider upgrading the plan ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, getJSON was returning a string value for a key for some users and that wherease it is expected to be boolean, just fixed it and it is working now, Thank you, You might consider adding your comment as an answer.

Comment: I actually spend the last 20 minutes writing a SO docs section for next time someone has this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database#t=201609192212047137718 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `setValue()` will create the path if it doesn't exist yet.

It seems more likely that your `user.getJSON()` contains something that is invalid according to the database (or your security rules).

You'll want to [attach a completion block](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference.html#a1107cae145ab12e1ef58ab9f8713b84d) to detect this.

Here is an example of doing this from the StackOverflow Documentation:

> A frequent reason why your read operation may not work is because your
>   security rules reject the operation, for example because you're not
>   authenticated (by default a database can only be accessed by an
>   authenticated user).
>
> You can see these security rule violations in the Console output. But
>   it's easy to overlook these. You can also handle them in your own code
>   and make them more prominently visible, which is especially useful
>   during development (since your JSON, rules and code change often).
>
> To detect a failed read on iOS you must implement the `withCancel`
>   block of your observer:
>
> ```
> ref!.child("notAllowed").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
>     print("Got non-existing value: \(snapshot.key)")
> }, withCancel: { (error) in
>     print(error)
> })
> ```